# Correct structure of implementing MVVM LiveData RxJava Dagger Databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, rx-java2, android-livedata, dagger

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var mainViewModelFactory: mainViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var mainActivityBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_main
        )

        mainActivityBinding.rvmainRepos.adapter = mainAdapter
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        mainViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        mainViewModelFactory
                )[mainViewModel::class.java]
        mainActivityBinding.viewmodel = mainViewModel
        mainActivityBinding.lifecycleOwner = this
        mainViewModel.mainRepoReponse.observe(this, Observer<Response> {
            repoList.clear()
            it.success?.let { response ->
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    //     mainViewModel.saveDataToDb(response)
                    //     mainViewModel.createWorkerForClearingDb()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**MainViewModelFactory**

```
class MainViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        val mainRepository: mainRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>) =
            with(modelClass) {
                when {
                    isAssignableFrom(mainViewModel::class.java) -> mainViewModel(
                            mainRepository = mainRepository
                    )
                    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: ${modelClass.name}")
                }
            } as T
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel(
        val mainRepository: mainRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    val mainRepoReponse = MutableLiveData<Response>()
    val loadingProgress: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val _loadingProgress: LiveData<Boolean> = loadingProgress
    val loadingFailed: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    val _loadingFailed: LiveData<Boolean> = loadingFailed
    var isConnected: Boolean = false

    fun fetchmainRepos() {
        if (isConnected) {
            loadingProgress.value = true
            compositeDisposable.add(
                    mainRepository.getmainRepos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe({ response ->
                                run {
                                    saveDataToDb(response)
                                    )
                                }
                            },
                                    { error ->
                                        processResponse(Response(AppConstants.Status.SUCCESS, null, error))
                                    }
                            )
            )
        } else {
            fetchFromLocal()
        }
    }

    private fun saveDataToDb(response: List<mainRepo>) {
        mainRepository.insertmainUsers(response)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(object : DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                    override fun onComplete() {
                        Log.d("Status", "Save Success")
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Log.d("Status", "error ${e.localizedMessage}")
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

**MainRepository**

```
interface MainRepository {

    fun getmainRepos(): Single<List<mainRepo>>

    fun getAllLocalRecords(): Single<List<mainRepo>>

    fun insertmainUsers(repoList: List<mainRepo>): Completable
}
```

**MainRepositoryImpl**

```
class mainRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
        val apiService: GitHubApi,
        val mainDao: AppDao
) : MainRepository {

    override fun getAllLocalRecords(): Single<List<mainRepo>> = mainDao.getAllRepos()

    override fun insertmainUsers(repoList: List<mainRepo>) :Completable{
        return   mainDao.insertAllRepos(repoList)
    }

    override fun getmainRepos(): Single<List<mainRepo>> {
        return apiService.getmainGits()
    }
}
```

I'm quite confused with the implementation of MVVM with LiveData and Rxjava, in my MainViewModel I am calling the interface method and implementing it inside ViewModel, also on the response I'm saving the response to db. However, that is a private method, which won't be testable in unit testing in a proper way (because it's private). What is the best practice to call other methods on the completion of one method or i have to implement all the methods inside the implementation class which uses the interface.

Comment: You can chain the two rxjava calls `mainRepository.getmainRepos().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).flatMapCompletable { mainRepository.insertMainUsers(response) }.observeOn(..).subscribe(..)`

Comment: Also, you're missing `@Inject constructor` in your `MainViewModel`.

Comment: @sonnet That's okay, if they are chainable, what if they are not related to each other. If i write a private method it won't be accessible for testing, not only that, it i include that code in the above function it'll break the SRP

Comment: You could break things down and move some stuff to interactors/usecases/repositories. For example, this two rx calls could go to a separate interactor. Also, your private functions are tested as a result of testing your public functions. An example: [1](https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/blob/master/data/src/main/java/app/tivi/data/repositories/followedshows/FollowedShowsRepository.kt#L93)

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should not care how you are getting the data if you are trying to follow the clean architecture pattern. The logic for fetching the data from local or remote sources should be in the repository in the worst case where you can also save the response. In that case, since you have a contact for the methods, you can easily test them. Ideally, you could break it down even more - adding Usecases/Interactors.